# How to simplify $(\frac{\sin\alpha - \sin\beta}{\cos\beta -\cos\alpha})\cdot \cos\alpha \cdot \cos\beta$?

Tags: trigonometry

There is this problem:
$$\left(\frac{\sin\alpha - \sin\beta}{\cos\beta -\cos\alpha}\right)\cdot \cos\alpha \cdot \cos\beta = \frac{1}{\tan\alpha -\tan\beta}$$
I started as $$\left(\frac{\sin\alpha - \sin\beta}{\cos\beta -\cos\alpha}\right)\cdot \cos\alpha \cdot \cos\beta = \frac{\sin2\alpha \cos\beta-\sin2\beta \cos\alpha}{2(\cos\beta -\cos\alpha)}$$ but I'm stuck here, because I don't see how could I use $\sin(x-y)$ but also don't see how could I use any other identity without complicating this even more.

Comment: I think you need to divide your result that you worked out by 2 (as $\sin2x=2\sin x \cos x$)

Comment: Write everything in terms of sin and cos. Then multiply through by all denominators to get a polynomial equation in sin and cos

Comment: @A-LevelStudent Corrected.

Comment: What is the question ? "How to simplify..."... is the problem to prove the identity? Or to simplify the equality and solve for all possible pairs $ (\alpha, \beta)$ ?

Comment: @AdamRubinson good point, I assumed we were proving an identity, as the question made no mention of solving an equation. If we are indeed solving an equation, then the question makes more sense, as the 'identity' is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proposed identity is not true (even though after the correction).

Indeed, take $\alpha = \pi/4$ and $\beta = 0$. Then we obtain:
\begin{align*}
\left(\frac{\sin(\pi/4) - \sin(0)}{\cos(0) - \cos(\pi/4)}\right)\times\cos(\pi/4)\cos(0) = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2 - \sqrt{2}}\times\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} = \frac{1}{2-\sqrt{2}}
\end{align*}

On the other hand, one has that
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{2(\tan(\pi/4) - \tan(0))} = \frac{1}{2}
\end{align*}

**EDIT**

The proposed equation is equivalent to
\begin{align*}
\frac{(\sin(a) - \sin(b))\sin(a-b)}{\cos(b) - \cos(a)} = 1
\end{align*}

Comment: My bad. I happened to try out $2$ values that made the supposed answer only out by a factor of 2, hence my suggestions.

Comment: @A-LevelStudent No worries, it happens.

Comment: As noted by AdamRubinson the OP may in fact be attempting to solve an equation, not prove an identity.

Comment: I will edit my answer then. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: No problem, I also made that mistake initially.